# How to avoid form getting load twice when i select value from dropdown (h:selectOneMenu) in jsf xhtml page

Tags: jsf

Hi in below code when i select value from dropdown(h:selectOneMenu) it will call bean method twice. and prints two times in front end.
below is the code,

```
<h:body>
#{customerRoleFeature.init()}
<h:form id="custRoleFeatures" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="a_m_c">
<div class="title">Role Feature Inputs</div>
<div class="p_20">    
<div class="w360 f_l f13 ff_lato c_8 c_8_tf label_w100">
<div id="roledev" style="color:red;"/>
<label>Role Name:</label>
<h:selectOneMenu id="custRoleFeatureId" name="custRoleFeatureId" class="w242" value="# {customerRoleFeature.customerRoleId}" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select a name"/>
<f:selectItems value="#{customerRole.getActiveRoleList()}" var="u" itemLabel="#{u.customerName}" itemValue="#{u.customerRoleId}" />       
<f:ajax listener="#{customerRoleFeature.onSelectRole}"/>                                  </h:selectOneMenu>
<div id="ro" style="color:red;"/>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- cust_role_feature list START-->
<div class="box_01" style="width:675px;height:220px">
<div class="title">Feature List</div>
<table class="users_list">
<tr class="titles">
<td class="titles p_l_20" style="width:180px;">Feature Name</td>
<td class="titles p_l_20">Create</td>
<td class="titles p_l_20">View</td>    
<td class="titles p_l_20">Update</td>       
<td class="titles n_b_r">Delete</td>        
</tr>
</table>
```

-->
     
    
    #{a.getFeature().getName()}
    
    #{a.create}
    
    
    #{a.create}

```
<ui:fragment rendered = "#{a.view eq 'n'}">
<td class="last_name p_l_20"><input type="checkbox" id="viewId" name="viewId"  value="#{a.getFeature().getFeatureId()}">#{a.create}</input></td>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered = "#{a.view eq 'y'}">
<td class="last_name p_l_20"><input type="checkbox" id="viewId" name="viewId"  value="#{a.getFeature().getFeatureId()}" checked="true">#{a.create}</input></td>
</ui:fragment>

<ui:fragment rendered = "#{a.update eq 'n'}">
<td class="last_name p_l_20"><input type="checkbox" id="updateId" name="updateId"  value="#{a.getFeature().getFeatureId()}" >#{a.update}</input></td>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered = "#{a.update eq 'y'}">
<td class="last_name p_l_20"><input type="checkbox" id="updateId" name="updateId"  value="#{a.getFeature().getFeatureId()}" checked="true">#{a.update}</input></td>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered = "#{a.delete eq 'n'}">
<td class="last_name p_l_20"><input type="checkbox" id="deleteId" name="deleteId"  value="#{a.getFeature().getFeatureId()}" >#{a.delete}</input></td>
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered = "#{a.delete eq 'y'}">
<td class="last_name p_l_20"><input type="checkbox" id="deleteId" name="deleteId"  value="#{a.getFeature().getFeatureId()}" checked="true">#{a.delete}</input></td>
</ui:fragment>
</tr>
</ui:repeat>
</table></div>  
</div>
<h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{customerRoleFeature.addCustomerRoleFeature()}" onclick="return checkLikes();" class="bt_st_01 green_btn"/>  
</div>
```

Comment: What is it printing twice on the front end ?

Comment: data coming from backend. the data is in tabular format featureName create view delete update these are columns and data related to that. When i select value from drop down i am calling one jsf bean class method from that method i am printing data front end page. but when i select value two times that method is calling i want to avoid that but i am not getting how to avoid.

Comment: You have a form.submite method being called onChange which will submit the form everytime you change the value in the drop down. Also, there is an action listener, which will again call the backing bean method for every change in the drop down selection. Any reason why you are doing both ?>

Comment: In this form if i select value from dropdown. the select value i will access in jsf bean class with the help of that value i will access data from database then i will display that in the front end

Comment: You dont need to submit the for for that. in the action listener, call the method, update the model values with the new data you need on that page and then update only those components that you want to refresh with new data. Check the documentation for f:ajax for more details.